# Why drop-down menu is not working in codeigniter?

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I have a problem like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This code is working very well in independently.But when i integrate it with my website template it is not working.In my website I do like this.I create a view like this and i load it in a controller and pass it to a another view.In that particular view I do like this.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse ">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'Main'?>">Home</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><?=$navbar?></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'question'?>">Issues</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">SIGN UP</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how i load view in controller.

```
$data['navbar'] = $this->load->view('navbar', NULL, TRUE);
```

I have save the view file as navbar.php.

In that view, it is not working.How can I get solve this problem? I think it is a problem with css and js files are shuffling.

Comment: To see what HTML is being generated - view your HTML Source in your Browser. That will show you exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You are using template based on bootstrap so there definitely have a conflict with the [bootstrap dropdown class](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns)

Edit your classname in html and css for... `mydropdown`, `mydropdown-content` and it should be okey :]

[Here is the fixed version](https://jsfiddle.net/4sxs43m8/1/)

Css

```
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}

.mydropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.mydropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.mydropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.mydropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.mydropdown:hover .mydropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.mydropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

HTML :

```
  <div class="mydropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="mydropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: it is same as which i have included at the beginning of my question.

Comment: strange... It work for me. https://jsfiddle.net/4sxs43m8/ Can you check if the CSS is normally load?

Comment: CSS is normally load

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? Or some css library? `dropdown` seem to be frequently used... maybe there is a conflict with your class name

Comment: [link](https://bootstrapmade.com/company-free-html-bootstrap-template/)I tried it with this template.

Comment: I have update my solution, please check if it's working.